# Kivy - How to add multiple labels or buttons within a Label

Tags: python, layout, label, kivy

I have this code and I want to add on the second column multiple buttons instead of the only "Save" button, but maintaining only the one label of "TEST", I searched online but did not find anything

Im not using .kv files everything is in one file.

```
import kivy    
from kivy.app import App    
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import os

class ConnectPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text="TEST"))
        self.save = Button(text="Save")
        self.add_widget(self.save)    



class Epicapp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.connect_page = ConnectPage()
        screen = Screen(name="Connect")
        screen.add_widget(self.connect_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager



if __name__ == "__main__":
    chat_app = Epicapp()
    chat_app.run()
```

Comment: What's your barrier to adding more buttons?

Comment: What you mean by barrier?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a BoxLayout on the right side, orientation is 'vertical', and add buttons on it. Then, you add the BoxLayout to the root class

This is the code for it:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import os

class ConnectPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text="TEST"))
        self.mybox = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.button1 = Button(text="Load")
        self.button2 = Button(text="Cancel")
        self.save = Button(text="Save")
        self.mybox.add_widget(self.button1)
        self.mybox.add_widget(self.button2)
        self.mybox.add_widget(self.save)
        self.add_widget(self.mybox)



class Epicapp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.connect_page = ConnectPage()
        screen = Screen(name="Connect")
        screen.add_widget(self.connect_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager



if __name__ == "__main__":
    chat_app = Epicapp()
    chat_app.run()
```